# How can I get platform specific keybind information?

Tags: python, cross-platform, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I get the information on what's key bound for a specific function such as copying, for example in Windows it is <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>. How can I get that information with script?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, every system has its global shortcuts and only in some of them they are **partially** listed somewhere.